# Crackling sound when playing Youtube - Ubuntu 18.04.1 running on VirtualBox 6.0.2

Tags: sound, virtualbox, alsa

**Host OS -** Windows 10 64-bit
**Guest OS -** Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Using latest Virtual box (6.0.2) and already installed latest guest additions

In the virtualbox audio settings:
Host audio driver: Windows Directsound
Audio controller: ICHAC97 (other options are Intel HD audio and Soundblaster)

With ICHAC97, the youtube video is playing fine but audio is crackling and repeating.
If I change to Intel HD audio, the video doesn't play at all and of course no audio.

Comment: Having exactly same problem, also Win 10 64 bit host and Ubuntu 18.04 Guest. Still running on virtualbox 5.2.24 because Virtualbox 6 not able to boot my VMs at all. There are already lot of tickets on virtualbox.org about that problem with audio and video.

Comment: @AndiS. well that's a shame. Seems like the problem going on for a long time from reading forums.

Comment: Well maybe this could be of interest to some, I just installed a minimal Debian 9.6 and had exactly the same behavior you mentioned until I realized I haven't installed pulseaudio, so everything sounds like a charm, with Intel HD Audio by the way.

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. I followed this guide to install the GUI of pulse audio https://linuxhint.com/pulse_audio_sounds_ubuntu/ and then in the configuration tab, changed to profile from analog stereo duplex to analog stereo output. Using intel hd audio in virtualbox now and no crackling.

Comment: @AndiS. See first answer.

Comment: Also with newest Version I still have same Problems. The trick to change the profile works just about few minutes and then it is broken again.

Comment: I have the same issue, but running into VMWare. Have a look on it: https://askubuntu.com/a/1247401/8988

Answer (score 1):

Solved for me changing pulseaudio settings (`pavucontrol`) on a debian 10 to `analog stereo output` instead of `analog stereo duplex`
[image]